# Saving/Loading List of Classes to/from txt

Tags: c#

I have simple list of classes like this.

```
  public class Album
   {
       public int IDNumber { get; set; }
       public string AlbumName { get; set; }
       public string Artist { get; set; }
       public int ReleaseDate { get; set; }
       public int TrackAmount { get; set; }
       public string Location { get; set; }
       public int Rating { get; set; }

       public Album(int _id, string _name, string _artist, int _releasedate, int _trackamount, string _location, int _rating)
       {
           IDNumber = _id;
           AlbumName = _name;
           Artist = _artist;
           ReleaseDate = _releasedate;
           TrackAmount = _trackamount;
           Location = _location;
           Rating = _rating;
       }
   }
```

And I need to save it to file and also read it from file to list. I'm fairly new to C# and my methods from C++ won't work at all. Is there any simple way to do this? I would like it to look like in the file like this:

```
id albumname artist releasedate trackamout location rating
```

Is there any simple way of doing it?

Comment: What you're looking for is the term 'serialization'. I'm sure you'll find plenty of examples online on how to "serialize a class/struct".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [serialization](https://web.archive.org/web/20141231000000/http://tech.pro/tutorial/618/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file).

At the end of the page you will find an example as well!

Answer (score 0):

To save your list to a file, it could be something like this :

```
  // create a writer and open the file
  StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("myfile.txt");

  foreach(Album album in myListOfAlbum)
  {
    // write a line of text to the file
    stream.WriteLine(
      album.IDNumber.ToString() + " " + 
      album.AlbumName.ToString() + " " + 
      ...
      ...
    );
  }

  // close the stream
  stream.Close();
```

That said... indeed, using serialization would be the best approach if you want to load the list from the file too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question. [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) was what I was sugested to use which is very good. Try it out. 
Create an instance of `Album` object,say `albumObj` , then serialize the class to a file as

```
Album albumObj = new Album();

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\yourDirectory\example.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(albumObj));
```

All the public properties in the class `Album` that has "get" accessors will be serialized.
You could use `Formatting.Indented` to make your data more readable or use `JsonIgnore` to ignore some properties.
It would look like this

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\yourDirectory\example.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(albumObj, Formatting.Indented));
```

> Do not forget to install packages for [NewtonSoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NewtonSoft.Json). 
>   You can do that by going to Tools->NuGet Package Manager-> Package Manager Console then paste `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json` and press enter.

After which you can now import `using Newtonsoft.Json`